# htaccess Rewrite Rule Breaks Server-Sent Events (SSE) in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, server-sent-events

I'm facing an issue where my Server-Sent Events (SSE) aren't functioning correctly, and I suspect it's due to the .htaccess rewrite rules I'm using for my PHP application. I've narrowed down the problem, and when I bypass the rewrite rules, SSE works as expected.

Here's my .htaccess setup:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !favicon.ico(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

These rules essentially route all requests to index.php unless it's an actual file or directory on the server.

My SSE script is part of a larger application, and I suspect that routing through index.php might be causing interference, potentially due to output buffering, session locks, or other internal mechanisms of the application.

Here's php SSE script:

```
<?php 

ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');

// Set the appropriate headers for SSE
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-store');        
header('Connection: keep-alive');

ob_end_clean();
        
// Set a time limit for the script execution to 0 (no time limit)
set_time_limit(0);

$counter = 0;

while (true) {
    // If 10 updates have been sent, break out of the loop
    if ($counter >= 10) {
        echo "data: Stopping updates after 10 seconds.\n\n";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        break;
    }

    // Get the current time
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // Send the data to the client
    echo "data: The current server time is: {$time}\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    // Increment the counter
    $counter++;

    // Wait for 1 second before sending the next update
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue? How can I adjust my setup to ensure SSE works seamlessly with the rewrite rules in place? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: All the rewrite does is tell Apache which script to execute, after that the rewrite has zero effect on execution. If anything it's going to be the "larger application" interfering with the headers required.

Comment: I placed the SSE script at the beginning of index.php, but it doesn't work as expected in this configuration. Instead of chunking the response, it outputs the full response all at once. However, when the script is in a separate file, it functions correctly.